# Finding a recurrence relation for $f(n) = \begin{cases} a, &\text{for $n=1$}\\ f(n-1)+n^k,&\text{for $n>1$} \end{cases}$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

Working on a recurrence problem, as follows:
\begin{align}
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
a, &\text{for $n=1$}\\
f(n-1)+n^k,&\text{for $n>1$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
After a bunch of unrolling, I found this series: $f(n) = a + 2^k + \dots + (n-1)^k + n^k$

I'm meant to prove that $f(n) \leq c(n^{k+1})$, but I am stuck at this point and don't know how to further reduce this series.

Comment: Well actually $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n j^k = \Theta\left(n^{k+1}\right)$ (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for example), which will not be $\le c(n^k +1)$. Maybe double check you have written everything correctly.

Comment: There was a typo in the original post, it's $\leq c(n^{k+1})$ -- how does that series equal $n^{k+1}$ though? That's the bit I'm stuck on.

Comment: As [that link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) described, your series is a degree $k+1$ polynomial function of $n$. You can show as an exercise that if $d\in \mathbb{N}$, given any degree $d$ polynomial function of $n$, $P_{d}(n)$, there exists a constant $c$ such that $P_{d}(n) \le cn^d$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. (And $d$ is $k+1$ in your particular problem.) There is also a proof of that series formula on that page. However, you do not need that exact formula, it would suffice for you to show that the series is bounded above by something of the form $Cn^{k+1}$.

Comment: What's $c$? Just a constant?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I appreciate that, but I didn't understand even a little bit of the math on that wikipedia page. If you could explain like I'm a child why this is a degree $k+1$ polynomial, rather than a degree $k$ polynomial?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva yes, $c$ is just some constant that I will eventually need to prove exists, but I was struggling to understand how $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k = n^{k+1}$

Comment: You don't actually need to know that for the purposes of this problem. A loose bound is good enough. But just for an intuition, remember how integrating $x^k$ gives $x^{k+1}/(k+1)$? Well similarly *summing* $n^k$ will give (something like) $n^{k+1}/(k+1)$. (Intuitively, integration is like the continuous analog of summation, or summation is like discrete integration.)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth OK, I got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** Note that $f(n) = (a-1) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}j^k$. Try and show that if $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists a constant $C$ such that $S_k(n):= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}j^k \le Cn^{k+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Note that $j^k \le n^k$ for each $j=1,\ldots,n$.

Once you have shown this, you should be able to show that it follows that there is some constant $c$ such that $f(n)\le cn^{k+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. (E.g. because if $a>1$, then $a-1 \le (a-1)n^{k+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.)